# Extending Android activity from the library

Tags: java, android, inheritance, constructor

In my Android project I am using my custom Android library.

In this library I have defined followed Activity (part of the snippet):

```
public class MyLibAcitivity extends Activity {

    int  counter = 0;
    int[] results = new int[2];
```

In the main project I would like to extend this Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends MyLibAcitivity {
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
Implicit super constructor  is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

How I can make it works?

On the other side, maybe I have not correct approach. What I want to achieve, is to have all logic of the application in library and extend few classes (activities) to use different "data source" - my data source is for now another Java class. So basically, in main class I just want to change source to the local one, instead of taking data from library.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Must define an explicit constructor`

if you're on Eclipse you right click on the class code -> Source -> Generate Constructor from Superclass.

Answer (score 2):

add this to `MyLibAcitivity`

```
public MyLibAcitivity() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
    }
```